# Is it valid to create an object inside the constructor of class?

Tags: c++, object, constructor

Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
struct T
{
    public:
        T() : b(6)
        {
            T t=*this;  // copy constructor
            std::cout<<t;
        }
        int b;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const T& t);
}t;
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o,const T& t)
{
    o<<t.b<<'\n';
    return o;
}
int main() { }
```

The above program looks strange to me indeed. Is it fine to create object of the class inside constructor? Is this code's behavior well defined?

Comment: While technically valid, this is a bad idea. Please read: **[Should you use the this pointer in the constructor?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#using-this-in-ctors)**

Comment: The object is not considered to be constructed until the constructor has completed. I'm not so confident that this use of `*this` is correct

Comment: @M.M: why http://ideone.com/BsIm3G this program results in runtime error. When I compile & run it on my local machine on g++ 4.8.1 I got error message at runtime that test.exe has stopped working. why? what is the reason?

Comment: @PravasiMeet that program causes recursion because `T t;` occurs inside `T`'s default constructor

Comment: @M.M: oh I didn't notice about recursion. Thanks.

Comment: @M.M: Still I doubt that is it well defined behavior to write T t=*this; inside ctor. What you think sir?

Comment: @PravasiMeet I'm not sure

Comment: The second answer also explicitly addresses your second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is well defined. It is going to use a copy constructor, and the object is destructed when the constructor's body ends.

However, I find it quite weird piece of code, and I would have quite difficult time finding its proper use.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the traps about calling member functions from a constructor, particularly if they are virtual as the concrete type of the object is of the type which currently runs a constructor, not the leaf type.

Comment: @PravasiMeet that would be a question to ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine as long as you don't inadvertently call the same constructor recursively! I've seen many student programs that did exactly that, usually when trying to implement a linked list.

Comment: Re-entering the same constructor on different objects is not necessarily a problem. Recursion without termination is.

Comment: Indeed, as long as there's a base case. Seen plenty of student code where the first line of a constructor creates an instance of the same class with the same constructor unconditionally, however.